# Angular JS, factory returns data, but in controller it is gone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have started to learn something about AngularJS. I managed to create some simple controllers, but I would like to do a bit of refactoring and create also a factory.

Here is one of my js files:

```
angular
.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getOne: function () {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/login/login'})
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.info(data);
                    return data;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("failure");
                });
        }
    }
}])
.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
    $scope.user = UserFactory.getOne();
}]);
```

The program correctly prints the data to the console received from the servlet at that line: `console.info(data);`
But the controller does not return anything to the view. I put here also `console.info(UserFactory.getOne())` and it prints `undefined`.

Where is my coding mistake?

Comment: If you look at the code carefully you will see that you aren't returning anything from your getOne function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOne` needs to return a value, and in this case it'll be a promise from $http. The success method should return the value needed by the controller.

```
.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    getOne: function () {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/login/login'})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            });
    }
}
}]);
```

Now in your controller you can handle that result.

```
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
 UserFactory.getOne().then(function(data){
      $scope.user = data;
 });
}]);
```

The `success` and `failure` methods are depreciated. You should try using `then` instead.

```
.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    getOne: function () {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/login/login'})
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your factory return at the wrong place, so it return undefined. you can fix it by handling success in controller itself. try this.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
   return {
       getOne: function (callback) {
          $http({method: 'GET', url: 'request_url'})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                callback(data, status, headers, config);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure");
            });
    }
}
}]);

app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
     UserFactory.getOne(function(data){
          $scope.user = data;
     });
}]);
```

WORKING URL : [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iL1mkBrpS3hVjGPhzHYq?p=preview)